# Sinatra - values disappearing between route and view

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am using jquery / ajax to pass into a route two variables (from a slider), min and max.  At this point I just want the values and while I can see them in the route(console) and in the params, passing them into view, they are empty.
I haven't run into this before.

Right now the route is this -

```
post '/dir_scan' do
p @min = params[:min] 
p @max = params[:max]

  slim :listing, :layout => (request.xhr? ? false : :layout) 
end
```

listing is a partial, embedded in another view.

This is the view (using slim)

```
 p "#{@min}"
 p "#{@min}"
```

I checked docs, but didn't really find anything as to the cause. I did try using the locals hash with no change in the behavior. My thinking is that while I'm not returning anything yet to jquery, the route is hit and it should reload with the values.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are those `p`s actually in your code? You should remove them.

Comment: In development, so it's just for me to see what is going on.

Comment: What do you see in the browser? What’s your js code to display it? Have you tried making a normal (non-ajax) request, and what happens when you do?

Comment: In the browser I see "", aka empty, string. I haven't tried it non ajax.  Not a bad idea, I'll try it, but I assumed since params is capturing the values as is, shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I am not using any js code to display it.  Still contemplating just having the partial update regular but with the ability to input the parameters via the slider.